# Cannot checkout as a guest in Magento 2.3.2

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, payment, guest-checkout

I'm currently getting an error with my Magento 2.3.2 site.

When users check out as guests they are getting the following error.

> No such entity with cartId = gRO8kO0ylqMViKh6sR06ZQJ5aR9RavdJ

I'v checked in the developer console and the following error is given:

```
VM3294 jquery.js:10254 POST https://www.mywebsite.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/gRO8kO0ylqMViKh6sR06ZQJ5aR9RavdJ/payment-information 404 (Not Found)
send    @   VM3294 jquery.js:10254
ajax    @   VM3294 jquery.js:9738
post    @   VM3519 storage.js:41
(anonymous) @   VM6585 place-order.js:21
(anonymous) @   VM6581 place-order.js:35
_super  @   VM3386 wrapper.js:73
(anonymous) @   VM6579 place-order-mixin.js:19
(anonymous) @   VM3386 wrapper.js:78
getPlaceOrderDeferredObject @   VM6575 default.js:165
placeOrder  @   VM6575 default.js:139
(anonymous) @   VM3345 knockout.js:4255
dispatch    @   VM3294 jquery.js:5226
elemData.handle @   VM3294 jquery.js:4878
```

I've tried updating the Sagepay extension but this does not seem to have done anything.

Does anyone know another reason this could be occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently this was a problem with an extension called SetuBridge Country Group Manager.

It was necessary to contact the Extension provider and have the extension updated to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

go to **Store / Sales / Checkout /** Allow Guest Checkout => must be set to "Yes"

Comment: Just checked and it is set to yes.

Comment: Magent calls this method when you click place order:  $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);

make sure you have corrects informations